# How to learn a neural network based on a cost function in an unsupervised way?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, optimization, unsupervised-learning

I need to learn a neural network that predicts L (see equation below). So based on three points from a discrete trajectory I want to learn L by minimizing the equation below, which is a physical equation that has some properties I want to ensure they are conserved.

$$D_1L(q(k-1), q(k)) + D_2L(q(k),q(k+1)) = 0$$

Here $D$ is the derivative with respect to ith argument of L. This can be obtained via automatic differentiation and it is fully compatible with backpropagation.

Here is the concrete problem I am trying to solve:

```
1 - q(k-1) , q(k) and q(k+1) are the inputs of the neural net L.

2 - Note that the cost function we are trying to minimize is not a direct consequence of the target value.
```

Is this solvable using neural networks? Can I learn L by minimizing the cost function above?

Comment: There's a trivial solution: $L = 0$ for all inputs. You are missing other properties to make this solvable.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. With that statement you mean to learn the NN to predict always zero for the cost function?

Comment: If $L$ is constant for all inputs, then the derivatives are zero, thus making the equality true, irrespective of the inputs. That's the trivial solution.

Comment: Well, L is the lagrangian of a system. It is not constant it just follows the equation. Sorry If I wasn't ilustrative enough.